# Как сделать так, чтобы в браузере Chrom никогда не появлялось окно разрешений на уведомления

Tags: google-chrome, администрирование

Как сделать так, чтобы в браузере Chrom никогда не появлялось окно разрешений на уведомления? Ни для одного сайта. Может быть какой-то аддон надо поставить, или в настройках где-то есть отключение? Можно ли полностью отключить это окно, или Гугл настаивает на том, чтобы я каждый раз отказывал сайту в уведомлениях вручную?

Comment: chrome://settings/content/notifications  чекбокс в положение `off`. Судя по тексту, должно помочь.

Comment: @zhurof Вы будете смеяться, но у меня в Хроме нет папки chrome://settings/content/. У меня хром русифицированный, но в адресной строке появляется английское название раздела. Есть разделы people, autofill, appearance, search, defaultBrowser, onStartup, privacy, languages, downloads, printing, accessibility, system, reset. А раздела content нет. :-(

Comment: @zhurof Я нашел раздел content. Но это не тот переключатель. Если его снять, то Хром действительно перестает запрашивать разрешение на уведомление. Но при этом Хром начинает всем сайтам разрешать слать мне уведомления. Это совсем не то, что нужно. Нужно запретить и спрашивать разрешение на уведомления и также нужно запретить храму самому разрешать сайтам слать уведомления.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перейдите по ссылке chrome://settings/content/notifications
Отключите параметр "Спрашивать разрешение перед отправкой"

Comment: Всем спасибо, все сработало.